# Can't display monetary format of the data PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is my code for the output of 1 row for the total 31295 and is correct.

```
SELECT  SUM(orders.quantity * products.price) as total
       FROM
        orders
       inner join products on products.id = orders.products_id
       inner join customers on customers.id = orders.customers_id WHERE order_date 
       BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days' 
       AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 days'
```

However, when I add,

```
SELECT  orders.quantity * products.price as total
to_char(orders.quantity * products.price, '$99,999,999.99') AS money,
      FROM
       orders
       inner join products on products.id = orders.products_id
       inner join customers on customers.id = orders.customers_id WHERE order_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days'
    AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 days'
    GROUP BY money
```

It kept displaying different values with more rows.

Comment: _It kept displaying different values_: please edit your question and include some of these values to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Of course you're going to get different results, you completely changed the query! The first one just sums all rows. The second one groups by the sum of each row. If each row's sum is different, well you'll get a row for each.